# How to host two websites on one AWS lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, subdomain, lets-encrypt, amazon-lightsail

I'm quite new to this whole website thing and I'm looking for some guidance on how to configure bitnami apache so I can have two websites on the same server.

I have a domain (which i'll call `example.com`) using route53 and pointed it to my lightsail LAMP instance. Now what I want to do is have one main site at either `www.example.com` or `example.com` and then another site at `test.example.com`. I would also like to get https running using letsencrypt if possible.

Could I configure it so that the file structure would be something along the lines of

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs
    /www
        main website here
    /test
        second website here
```

Would really appreciate any pointers on how to do this. I presume I need to create virtual hosts in the apache config files but I have no idea how to do that for different subdomains and have https as well.

Comment: please let me know if there are any logs of command outputs anyone needs

Comment: There are many tutorials for "how to host two / multiple websites on apache", like this one https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-18-04/